# Azure data factory pipeline for-each activity not working sequential

Tags: foreach, pipeline, azure-data-factory, sequential

I've azure data factory pipeline through which I need to pull my all CSV files from blob storage container and store that files to azure data lake container. Before storing those files to data lake I need to apply some data manipulation on that file's data.

Now I need to do this process sequentially and not parallel. So I use ForEach Activity->Settings->Sequential.

But it not working sequentially and works as a parallel process.

[image: Pipeline main activity panel]

[image: Pipeline foreach activity panel]
Below is the pipeline code

```
{
    "name":"PN_obfuscate_and_move",
    "properties":{
        "description":"move PN blob csv to adlgen2(obfuscated)",
        "activities":[
            {
                "name":"GetBlobFileName",
                "type":"GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn":[

                ],
                "policy":{
                    "timeout":"7.00:00:00",
                    "retry":0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds":30,
                    "secureOutput":false,
                    "secureInput":false
                },
                "userProperties":[

                ],
                "typeProperties":{
                    "dataset":{
                        "referenceName":"PN_Getblobfilename_Dataset",
                        "type":"DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList":[
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings":{
                        "type":"AzureBlobStorageReadSetting",
                        "recursive":true
                    },
                    "formatSettings":{
                        "type":"DelimitedTextReadSetting"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"ForEachBlobFile",
                "type":"ForEach",
                "dependsOn":[
                    {
                        "activity":"GetBlobFileName",
                        "dependencyConditions":[
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties":[

                ],
                "typeProperties":{
                    "items":{
                        "value":"@activity('GetBlobFileName').output.childItems",
                        "type":"Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential":true,
                    "activities":[
                        {
                            "name":"Blob_to_SQLServer",
                            "description":"Copy PN blob files to sql server table",
                            "type":"Copy",
                            "dependsOn":[

                            ],
                            "policy":{
                                "timeout":"7.00:00:00",
                                "retry":0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds":30,
                                "secureOutput":false,
                                "secureInput":false
                            },
                            "userProperties":[
                                {
                                    "name":"Source",
                                    "value":"PNemailattachment//"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"Destination",
                                    "value":"[dbo].[PN]"
                                }
                            ],
                            "typeProperties":{
                                "source":{
                                    "type":"DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings":{
                                        "type":"AzureBlobStorageReadSetting",
                                        "recursive":false,
                                        "wildcardFileName":"*.*",
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery":false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings":{
                                        "type":"DelimitedTextReadSetting"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink":{
                                    "type":"AzureSqlSink"
                                },
                                "enableStaging":false
                            },
                            "inputs":[
                                {
                                    "referenceName":"PNBlob",
                                    "type":"DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs":[
                                {
                                    "referenceName":"PN_SQLServer",
                                    "type":"DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Obfuscate_PN_SQLData",
                            "description":"mask specific columns",
                            "type":"SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                            "dependsOn":[
                                {
                                    "activity":"Blob_to_SQLServer",
                                    "dependencyConditions":[
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy":{
                                "timeout":"7.00:00:00",
                                "retry":0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds":30,
                                "secureOutput":false,
                                "secureInput":false
                            },
                            "userProperties":[

                            ],
                            "typeProperties":{
                                "storedProcedureName":"[dbo].[Obfuscate_PN_Data]"
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName":{
                                "referenceName":"PN_SQLServer",
                                "type":"LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"SQLServer_to_ADLSGen2",
                            "description":"move PN obfuscated data to azure data lake gen2",
                            "type":"Copy",
                            "dependsOn":[
                                {
                                    "activity":"Obfuscate_PN_SQLData",
                                    "dependencyConditions":[
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy":{
                                "timeout":"7.00:00:00",
                                "retry":0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds":30,
                                "secureOutput":false,
                                "secureInput":false
                            },
                            "userProperties":[

                            ],
                            "typeProperties":{
                                "source":{
                                    "type":"AzureSqlSource"
                                },
                                "sink":{
                                    "type":"DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings":{
                                        "type":"AzureBlobFSWriteSetting"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings":{
                                        "type":"DelimitedTextWriteSetting",
                                        "quoteAllText":true,
                                        "fileExtension":".csv"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging":false
                            },
                            "inputs":[
                                {
                                    "referenceName":"PN_SQLServer",
                                    "type":"DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs":[
                                {
                                    "referenceName":"PNADLSGen2",
                                    "type":"DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Delete_PN_SQLData",
                            "description":"delete all data from table",
                            "type":"SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                            "dependsOn":[
                                {
                                    "activity":"SQLServer_to_ADLSGen2",
                                    "dependencyConditions":[
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy":{
                                "timeout":"7.00:00:00",
                                "retry":0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds":30,
                                "secureOutput":false,
                                "secureInput":false
                            },
                            "userProperties":[

                            ],
                            "typeProperties":{
                                "storedProcedureName":"[dbo].[Delete_PN_Data]"
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName":{
                                "referenceName":"PN_SQLServer",
                                "type":"LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "folder":{
            "name":"PN"
        },
        "annotations":[

        ]
    },
    "type":"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: can you explain the source data set in the copy activity?

Comment: 1.Source in 'Blob_to_SQLServer' Copy Data activity is blobstorage container having csv filespath with @item().name as filename.
2.Source in 'SQLServer_to_ADLSGen2' Copy Data activity is specific table in SQL server.

Comment: Hi Manish, did you get answer for your question if yes please share as i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, the same process mentioned above worked, some bug was there in ADF released update at that time, which was resolved by Microsoft later on. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

The [ForEach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) in Azure Data Factory (ADF) by default runs up to 20 tasks in parallel.  You can make it run up to 50.  If you want to **force** it to run sequentially, ie one after the other, then you can either set the Sequential checkbox on the Settings section of the ForEach UI (see below) or set the `isSequential` property of the ForEach activity in the JSON to true, eg

[image: Data Factory UI]

```
{
    "name": "<MyForEachPipeline>",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "<MyForEachActivity>",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "isSequential": "true",
                    "items": {
...
```

I would caution the use of this setting though.  Running things in serial, ie one after the other will slow things down.  Is there another way you can design your workflow to take advantage of this really powerful feature of Azure Data Factory?  Then your job will only take as long as the longest task(s), rather than the cumulative total of all tasks together.

Let's say I have a job to run which has 10 tasks each taking 1 second.  If I run this job in serial it will take 10 seconds, but if I run it in parallel it will take 1 second.

SSIS never really had this - you could either manually create multiple paths or maybe use third-party components but it wasn't built in.  It's really a superb feature of ADF you should try and take advantage of.  There may of course be occasions where you really do need to run in serial which is why this option is available.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the nice explanation. As you can see in the question, I put that option checked. But still, It doesn't work as expected.
Also, update the question for full code for the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar.

I've only just started with ADF so could be wrong but I noticed that by default, there is a batch size set on the for each activity. I made sure to set this to 1 **as well as** setting the sequential checkbox and now the inner activities are running in the order I expected.

For anyone else facing this issue:

1. Unchecking the sequential checkbox then type 1 for the batch limit
2. Recheck the box. Note that I'm using the designer and can't see anything in the code view relating to batch size so maybe it's hidden.